# Why does this suggested change in a Python pyproj initalisation future warning result in an error?

Tags: python, proj, pyproj

I Recently updated to pyproj v2.6. and started getting future warnings when initalisating a Proj class like so:

```
Proj("+init=world:bng")
Proj("+init=EPSG:22770")
```

Both of these initalisations result in the following future warning:

```
FutureWarning: '+init=<authority>:<code>' syntax is deprecated. '<authority>:<code>' is the preferred initialization method. When making the change, be mindful of axis order changes: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#axis-order-changes-in-proj-6
```

So I make the following change, as the warning suggests:

```
Proj("world:bng")   # doesn't work
Proj("EPSG:22770")  # works
```

But I get an error for the world:bng case:

```
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: world:bng: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)
```

I have found a way round this, by defining world:bng using a proj4 string. But what I don't understand is why "world:bng" does not work?

Comment: I guess that Proj does not anymore support world:bng.  Doesn't it mean EPSG:27700?

Comment: I did switch to EPSG:22700 but this gave slightly different coordinates after transforming. I suppose that must be the case although I can't find any info about world:bng being dropped in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older Proj versions all the coordinate systems definitions were stored into text files. The files had names like "epsg", "esri", and "world". The text files had a keys, and the meaning of `+init=world.bng` was "entry bng in the file world".

In newer versions the official coordinate system definitions from EPSG, ESRI, and some other authorities are stored into a SQLite database named "proj.db" and fetched from there.

In new Proj the old syntax `+init=EPSG:4326` still works but Proj does not any more deliver resource file https://proj.org/resource_files.html "epsg" and definitions are taken from the database even with this syntax.

The resource file "world" still exists in the current Proj versions but the proj.db file does not contain a copy of those coordinate system shortcuts because authority "world" is not official. Therefore "world.bng" does not work (not found from proj.db) but "+init=world.bng" works (gets data from text file "world").

The section for bng in the text file is this

```
# other grids in DMA TM8358.1
<bng> # British National Grid
    proj=tmerc ellps=airy lat_0=49dN lon_0=2dW
    k_0=0.9996012717 x_0=400000 y_0=-100000
    no_defs <>
```

I believe that EPSG:27700 is what is supposed to be used with recent Proj and world.bng is there because of some historical reasons. Maybe it is that slight difference that you observed.

Comment: Thank for you the explination.